# Help identify late 80s or early 90s New Wave single

Tags: identify-this-song, new-wave

It's a song that I heard on the radio in the car with my parents driving (USA), so it probably isn't an underground/obscure single or group.

I remember the single was New Wave pop rock, the male vocals are very much like Duran Duran, Depeche Mode, Information Society and many other groups of that era.

For the music, I kind of remember piano instruments, but I could be wrong.

For the lyrics, the hook was something like "all I really want-ed" or "all I wanted was one-thing" or "since the day that I met-you."

The theme of the song sounds like somebody looking back on their life, or a relationship that already ended.

If it helps, I tried to [recreate the melody in Beepbox](https://beepbox.co/#8n31s0k0l00e02t2hm0a7g0fj07i0r0o3210T0v1L4u22q1d5f6y1z8C0w4c0h1T5v1L4u42q1d1f6y1z7C1c0h0H_RBHBziiii9998T3v1L4uaeq1d2f8y2z9C0Sp99f9c9Vppbaa9gT4v1L4uf0q1z6666ji8k8k3jSBKSJJAArriiiiii07JCABrzrrrrrrr00YrkqHrsrrrrjr005zrAqzrjzrrqr1jRjrqGGrrzsrsA099ijrABJJJIAzrrtirqrqjqixzsrAjrqjiqaqqysttAJqjikikrizrHtBJJAzArzrIsRCITKSS099ijrAJS____Qg99habbCAYrDzh00b4z000000000h4g000000014h000000004h400000000p21vKpZp7NQPY3IPYkf0UeCDV9SrvXIP-P8XCvArNTdDV3D3XezLr7NIJ4DuPYPtzVJnBXtvTtmpXCvSG7GGxWGEvjg9V-00000) (I'm definitely not a musician).

Can anyone identify this song?

Comment: I find that Googling for lyrics can identify a song very quickly, if you can get the exact wording right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "Enjoy the Silence" by Depeche Mode?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wy3MVRx7R0

Answer (score 0):

Too many possible matches based on description.

Might be:

- [DeVision - You are the one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qMepyYrEmo)
- [Wolfsheim - One thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DD2pVoCUjp0)
- [And one - Sometimes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkd4S9nLWTI)

Specially look for more songs of DeVision and Wolfsheim, if you find the voices familiar.
A lot of their songs are about past life regrets.